# Cd to a project nested deep inside the tree of folders

Tags: shell, command-line

cd /Users/user/Desktop/project - that command works.

I'd like to cd to a project by typing /Users/**/project but it doesn't work.

How can I cd to a project nested deep inside?

Comment: This is operating system specific and shell specific. On Linux, consider using [zsh](http://zsh.org/), after configuring it properly (in your `~/.zshrc` file) and after reading the documentation of `zsh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that globstar (**) is not supported in earlier versions of the bash (< 4.0). The solution was to update the bash to the latest version.